# Issue with useInteractiveGuideline() in nvd3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a chart object which uses interactive guideline:

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true);
[...]
```

If I later (say during an event) clear the chart via something like this:

```
d3.select("#{{id}} > *").remove();
```

Then the problem for me is that whilst the chart area is made blank (as desired), the mouse tooltip / interactive guideline remains.

My question is: How can I remove the interactive guideline at the same time that the chart is removed?

Comment: I'm not sure, if you can do it, but I would change the question headline to contain the word "remove".

Answer (score 2):

Before running `d3.select("#{{id}} > *").remove();` you can run

```
d3.select("#{{id}}")
  .on("mousemove", null)
  .on("mouseout", null)
  .on("dblclick", null)
  .on("click", null);
```

and d3 will remove the event listeners.

Look at the documentation https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on

Answer (score 0):

`d3.select` only finds the first element matching the selector.  In this situation that would be the `svg` of the plot but not the `tooltip` which is a `div` **sibling** of the `svg`.

Instead use `selectAll`, which would find the `svg` and `div`:

```
d3.selectAll("#{{id}} > *").remove();
```